# Seekbar for mp3 player in Actionscript 3.0 Flash CS-6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, progress-bar, mp3, seekbar

I'm trying to create a music player in Flash CS6. I'm new to Flash. I have created the play/pause/volume buttons. I have also been able to extract the mp3 information using the id3 tags. So i have the song duration. I now need to create a seekbar/progress bar. I have taken the progress bar from the components, but do not understand how to code it now. Please help!

Comment: It might be easier to leave components alone and make your own. For example : Make a rectangle that represents seek bar (convert to MovieClip object). Divide song duration by width of rectangle MC. Add mouse click listener to MC and when it's clicked check mouse's `x` pos. That pos is your **offset**  that you can use in the answer below...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [reference on `Sound.play()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play()):

```
public function play(startTime:Number = 0, loops:int = 0, sndTransform:flash.media:SoundTransform = null):SoundChannel
```

where the first argument is

```
startTime:Number (default = 0)//The initial position in milliseconds at which playback should start.
```

so you can call

```
channel.stop();
channel = sound.play(offset);
```

There is an example in the reference. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some idea using my audio player on my [Github page](https://github.com/Virajtharinda/Customizable-audio-player-for-flash).Also it's developed using flash CS6 and ActionScript 3.0. Use it, change it and develop your future with ActionScript .

Comment: I wanted to upvote this but it's too much. Keep it simple. This will confuse a beginner. You've involved external tween engines and scrollbar sliders etc. A simple & basic example of how to make an mp3's audio position play based on a click on a (simple) seek bar would have been good or even correct answer.